Postfix OS X not functioning
I need help with postfix on OSX. Testing with this command:
echo "test email" | mail -s  "test email" jeff@m1.lan```

Doesn't produce output in /var/mail/jeff
postfix is running:
sudo postfix status
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 8781

I also don't see postfix log activity in /var/log/ or via:
 sudo log stream --predicate 'sender == "postfix"'

My main.cf file is included.
compatibility_level = 2
queue_directory = /private/var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = _postfix
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = _postdrop
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
message_size_limit = 10485760
mailbox_size_limit = 0
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
myhostname = m1.lan
mydestination = m1.lan, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myorigin  = m1.lan
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24 172.18.0.0/16 172.19.0.0/16 172.17.0.0/16
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination


Testing with telnet:
jeff@m1 Desktop $ telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 m1.lan ESMTP Postfix
ehlo localhost
mail from: jeff@localhost
rcpt to: jeff@localhost
data
Subject: My first mail on Postfix

hello world
250-m1.lan
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10485760
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
250 2.1.0 Ok
250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>

.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 016CF5AB29C7
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
jeff@m1 Desktop $ mailq
Mail queue is empty


get your logs working first.

Love to. But how?

Getting logs working on MacOS is a separate question and probably off-topic here.

No, logs are working for everything but postfix. I think it's directly on topic for my issue.
